# Changing the design of a message box in Microsoft Access? VBA

Tags: ms-access, messagebox

So I can't really find anything specific on this, because I don't think you can actually do what I'm trying to do..

Basically, when pressing 'MessageButton', a message box will be displayed

```
Private Sub MessageButton_Click()
MsgBox ("Hello World")
End Sub
```

I want to know if there is a way of changing the background colour, text colour, border colour etc. of a message box?

The only way I could possibly think of doing this, would be to create the message box as a form instead, and then edit the form properties. But then I feel that creating multiple forms to be used as message boxes are a waste of resources.. aren't they? Or is it a viable option?

Comment: Are you concerned only with displaying a message, or do you also need to process Yes/No/Cancel types of responses to the message?

Comment: IMVHO you shouldn't - it is a good thing if a MessageBox looks like a MessageBox and not like something from outer space, and is instantly recognizable. As an additional bonus, with default MessageBoxes the text (!) can be copied with Ctrl+c when the MessageBox has the focus. Very useful for support.

Comment: @Andre If you're talking about VBA `MsgBox()`, how do you copy its "Prompt" text?

Comment: @HansUp: When the MsgBox has the focus, press Ctrl+c. Paste to a text editor. You get the title bar text, message text, button text(s). It works with programs that use the standard Windows messagebox, but many don't (then you only can do PrtScn).

Comment: @Andre I thought you meant first select the text, then Ctrl+c.  I never thought to try just Ctrl+c. Thanks!

Comment: @HansUp Yes, it's just a confirmation message really about logging into the database. But it doesn't look very nice because of the default bland looking style

Comment: @Andre Although I see your point, however I wouldn't be making drastic changes to it. I would just be changing the background colour and text colour to go with the theme a bit better

Answer (score 2):

There is, but it is a major task:

[Modern/Metro style message box and input box for Microsoft Access 2013](http://rdsrc.us/ocNV1c)

However, the above is a direct "plugin" which requires nothing but a single *find-n-replace* of your existing code.

Comment: Nice work on that, Gustav.  To be fair, it's not "a single find-and-replace", it's a 3rd Party tool, but it looks pretty slick with the Win8 schema.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: Thanks, but it is designed by intention so all you need is to import the modules and replace `MsgBox` with `MsgMox` in all your modules.

Answer (score 2):

No, this can't be done.  You will have to code your own messagebox and handle the Yes/No/Cancel functionality on your own.

There are a few "3rd Party" messageboxes that already exist, you can take a look at [this one](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2008/ms-access-enhanced-message-box-replacement/) and possibly work it into your application.